# Write feature collection to S3

Tags: python, geopandas, fiona, amazon-s3

Is there a way to write a feature collection from Python memory to an S3 bucket (as Esri Shapefile, zipped Shapefile or something else) without writing it first to disk?

I tried writing to a `ZipMemoryFile` for later pushing it to s3 with `boto3`'s `upload_fileobj` but it seems `ZipMemoryFile` are readonly

```
import fiona
from fiona.io import ZipMemoryFile
import boto3

# Initialize s3 client
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

# Read example feature collection
with fiona.open('fiona/tests/data/coutwildrnp.shp') as src:
    fc = list(src)
    meta = src.meta

# Write feature collection to file object
with ZipMemoryFile() as memfile:
    with memfile.open(path='test.shp', **meta) as dst:
        for feature in fc:
            dst.write(feature)

# Push to s3
s3.upload_fileobj(memfile, bucket, path)
```

The code above fails with a `fiona.errors.DriverError: '/vsizip/vsimem/f588438c-3a3e-4f9c-80eb-c1f244911f96.zip/test.shp' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name.`

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/23613145/125400

Comment: and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48493537/125400

Answer (score 1):

ZipMemoryFile is read only so far. https://fiona.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fiona.html#fiona.io.ZipMemoryFile

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).